# LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL with escape from string

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a problem within load a CSV file into MySQL database

the CSV file is like this:

```
stuID,stuName,degreeProg
6902101,A001,null
6902102,A002,null
6902103,A003,null
6902104,A004,null
6902105,A005,null
```

I have write a script like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'demo.csv' INTO TABLE `table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)
```

What troubles me is that:

1. the third column in file is `null` but when loading into the table, it becomes `'null'` (the string)
2. at the end of the file, there is a extra empty line, which will be also loaded and assigned with `null`

How should I write the script to deal with those 2 questions? (It is forbidden to modify the csv file) (and it's better to try to reduce the warning from MySQL when runs this script )

Comment: What warnings do you get?

Answer (score 1):

1) one option is to have the `LOAD DATA` assign the value of the third field (i.e. the string `'null') into a user defined variable, and use the`"SET col = expr"`form to assign a value to the column`col3`.

As an example:

```
    (`col1`, `col2`, @field3)
    SET col3 = IF(@field3='null',NULL,@field3)
```

---

2) There's no way to have MySQL LOAD DATA "skip" the last record in the file. To have MySQL ignore the last line, that would be better handled outside MySQL. For example, have MySQL LOAD DATA read from a named pipe, and have a separate concurrent process read the CSV file and write to that named pipe.

Comment: Could also delete the NULL row after the `LOAD DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could modify the CSV file, simply add `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'` and change `null` to `NULL` (upper case) to get them to load as `NULL`. Alternatively, use `\N` to load in `NULL`.

Also, obviously, delete the empty line at the end (which is most likely causing the warnings):

```
stuID,stuName,degreeProg
6902101,A001,\N
6902102,A002,\N
6902103,A003,\N
6902104,A004,\N
6902105,A005,\N
```